# When is the vtable used?

Tags: c++

Is the vtable only used for virtual function lookups, or does it get used for normal member function lookups as well?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Technically, this is an implementation detail.  The C++ standard says nothing about vtables or vptrs.

But typically, a compiler will only choose to use the vtable/vptr mechanism when a member function is being called in a polymorphic sense (i.e. via a pointer/referene to base class).  If it knows at compile-time what to do, then there's no need for the indirection.

Answer (score 3):

Only for virtual function lookups. A non-virtual member function doesn't require much special -- it's just a normal function that receives `this` as a hidden parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The standard doesn't dictate how inheritance is implemented, so a vtable doesn't necessarily exist. But as far as I know all the current major compilers only use vtables to call virtual functions.

Answer (score 1):

dynamic_cast would also use the vtable, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the vtable is only created (and thus used) when that method being called is specified as Virtual.  If it's virtual, then it will use the vtable, if it is not virtual, then it will be statically binded.

This determination is done at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

This is always implementation dependent, but most of the compilers will use vtable when:

- `virtual` function is being called;
- when using dynamic_cast addresses of vtables are used. Actual vtable is not used, but it must exist to have an address.
- `virtual`-y inherited class is being accesed.

`virtual`-y inherited class access includes both virtual and non-virtual method calls, but also field access, and even pointer casting

```
class foo{
public:
    virtual void bar(){}
};

class foo2: public virtual foo{
public:
    virtual void bar2(){}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    foo2* f2= new foo2();
    f2->bar();
    foo* f1 = f2;
}
```

Line `foo* f1 = f2;` will also read vtable (although firstly check will be made for f2==NULL, in such case f1 will be also NULL).

Answer (score -1):

And method pointer lookup. There is at least a check to see if the pointer points on virtual member function.

Comment: A check?  When is a check performed?

Comment: Doesn't compiler know at compile time what is virtual and what is not?

Comment: When a method pointer is called the last bit is tested: if it is a 1 it is a pointer towards a virtual method otherwise it is a pointer to a member function. You can easily check with objdump. You can also check the size of the member function pointer, it is not only a pointer. Actually it is an offset + the address or the index in the vtable of the method to call.

Comment: It is true on gcc at least. I don't know how it works on MSVC.