# Has the compiler optimized-out the virtual call?

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, polymorphism, vtable

I have this C++ which creates two derived objects and then invokes a virtual function call many times:

```
Parent* d;
Child1 d1[1];
Child2 d2[1];

if(__rdtsc() & 1 != 0){
    d = d1;
}
else{
    d = d2;
}

for(unsigned long long i =0; i<9000000000; ++i){
    sum += d->process2();
}
```

and it produces this assembler:

```
        for(unsigned long long i =0; i<9000000000; ++i){
000000013F4241A5  mov         qword ptr [rsp+100h],0  
000000013F4241B1  jmp         main+2B6h (013F4241C6h)  
000000013F4241B3  mov         rax,qword ptr [rsp+100h]  
000000013F4241BB  inc         rax  
000000013F4241BE  mov         qword ptr [rsp+100h],rax  
000000013F4241C6  mov         rax,218711A00h  
000000013F4241D0  cmp         qword ptr [rsp+100h],rax  
000000013F4241D8  jae         main+306h (013F424216h)  
            sum += d->process2();
000000013F4241DA  mov         rax,qword ptr [rsp+0F8h]  
000000013F4241E2  mov         rax,qword ptr [rax]  
000000013F4241E5  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rsp+0F8h]  
000000013F4241ED  call        qword ptr [rax+8]  
000000013F4241F0  mov         qword ptr [rsp+1D8h],rax  
000000013F4241F8  mov         rax,qword ptr [rsp+1D8h]  
000000013F424200  mov         rcx,qword ptr [sum (013F4385D8h)]  
000000013F424207  add         rcx,rax  
000000013F42420A  mov         rax,rcx  
000000013F42420D  mov         qword ptr [sum (013F4385D8h)],rax  
        }
```

Based on the assembler could somebody please confirm that the compiler cannot optimize the virtual call in the loop (even though every iteration calls the same derived object) because the compiler cannot possibly know whether `d1` or `d2` was selected, due to the call to `__rdtsc()` only being resolvable at run-time?

(If anyone could give me some advice how to read the assembler for the `d->process2()` call it would be most appreciated)

Comment: That code doesn't look optimized at all? Did you turn on optimizations?

Comment: Just turned on /03, full program optimization and favour code speed -> same output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
000000013F4241DA  mov     rax,qword ptr [rsp+0F8h] //load "this" into rax
000000013F4241E2  mov     rax,qword ptr [rax]      //load vtable pointer
000000013F4241E5  mov     rcx,qword ptr [rsp+0F8h] //load "this" into rcx
000000013F4241ED  call    qword ptr [rax+8]        //call second entry in vtable?
```

Clearly, call to virtual function is not optimized away. You are right, it is because of random factor.

Comment: How does this answer explain the "lack" of optimization?

Answer (score 1):

The compiler would not be able to inline the virtual call because, yes, it would be unable to know which object d1 or d2 would be used, therefore allowing for two possible inline results. Additionally, as a virtual call, there may be additional overhead for vtable lookups.

My recommendation, if you want to try to optimize yourself, would be to instead write something similar to

```
if(__rdtsc() & 1 != 0){
    for(unsigned long long i =0; i<9000000000; ++i){
        sum += d1[0].process2();
    }
}
else{
    for(unsigned long long i =0; i<9000000000; ++i){
        sum += d2[0].process2();
    }
}
```

though this still may be unable to optimize if process2 is a virtual call, and there is always a chance that inlining will not occur.

All in all, virtual calls always add overhead, and if clock cycles are important, it might do well to avoid.  You may look into [Static Polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) which loses some flexibility but can transfer costs from runtime to compile time.

Edit in response to user997112 below:
Static Polymorphism doesn't work for exactly the situation described above, but could be used to simplify my example a bit, but putting the for loop in a function:

```
void iterate_a_bunch( Parent<Child> &f )
{
    for(unsigned long long i =0; i<9000000000; ++i){
      f.process2();
    }
}
```

This function would compile twice, once for Child1 and once for Child2, leading to larger code size, but potentially boosted runtimes.

Comment: Obviously the above example wouldn't be able to work with static polymorphism because __rdtsc() is a run-time function? I presume static poly. only works when the conditional can be resolved at compile time?

Comment: If using derived instances, no virtual table lookup is performed.

Comment: @Eric- can you elaborate? You've just got me questioning my own understanding?!

Comment: d1 and d2 are declared as Child instances(array but anyway, not reference or pointer). In this case, there is no dynamic dispatch. If no class inherits from Child, even using a pointer would skip virtual table lookup.

Comment: Eric, I believe that whether or not the vtable is used may vary between compilers.  Likely it would not, but it may depend on implementation of the object and compiler http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167320/when-is-the-vtable-used

Answer (score 0):

I did the experiment with g++ and with -O3 it looks optimized. However, I have to say that the optimization looks exactly the same as what dvntehn00bz offers in his answer.

```
400860:       48 8b 45 00             mov    0x0(%rbp),%rax
400864:       48 89 ef                mov    %rbp,%rdi
400867:       ff 50 10                callq  *0x10(%rax)
40086a:       48 83 eb 01             sub    $0x1,%rbx
40086e:       75 f0                   jne    400860 <main+0x40>
```

The whole code has two loops, completely automatically.

P.S. Of course, your classes are probably a lot more complex than my slim version so the optimization is certainly much easier for the compiler.

Comment: How does this answer any question? It only says you did some testing and here are results. Please don't post something like this when you prosecute my answer for lack of the  point. The question is: "Has the compiler optimized-out the virtual call?"

Comment: I do say that dvntehn00bz has the right answer and yes you still don't.